# How to convert String (containing a table of numbers without comma delimiter) into Array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, string, type-conversion

I have a CSV file and I load it by "pd.read_csv". One of the columns is a variable with String datatype. But, it actually contains a table of numbers (like a 2D array) without comma delimiter.

I would like to convert it into Array. I tried "eval()" function but it gives an error (as can be seen in the following image).

If you have any idea how to solve this issue, please let me know.

[image]

Comment: how about using `split()`,    `sigma_profile_0.split()`

Comment: Show us whatyou have tried..

Comment: I tried:  z = sigma_profile_0.split(), and then: [eval(x) for x in z[1:-1]]. It gives me a list of numbers. That is fine. z[0] and z[-1] are brackets, so I exclude them.